# BIP70 signed payment request

Tags: ruby, bip70-payment-protocol

I am using https://github.com/bumi/bip70-example to make signed payment request. I bought COMODO Wildcard certificate. And creating certificates bundle in following order: `mydomain_origin.com.crt`, `comodorsadomainvalidationsecureserverca.crt`, `comodorsaaddtrustca.crt`, `addtrustexternalcaroot.crt`. And specifying this bundle and private key to the code. But when trying to make a payment wallet(Bread wallet for this example) giving me: "payee identity isn't cerfied. This operation couldn't be completed. (OSStatusError -9809)."